# Secure Webservice best practices

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, soap

I’m building a webservice and having some troubles witch option I should choose. Therefor I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction. I found many articles but none of them have more or less the options then I want.

What I want the webservice to do:
Client should get a WSDL derived from the ASMX file. Within that service there is one unauthenticated webmethod called “Authenticate(string Username, String Password)” that returns a custom AuthenticationSoapHeader. The AuthenticationSoapHeader is exactly and  preferably same as the System.Web.Security.FormsAuthenticationTicket class that is used in the webapplication.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4398/Authentication-for-Web-Services-using-SOAP-headers

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27365/Authenticate-NET-Web-Service-with-Custom-SOAP-Head

I’m thinking of using the articles above to implement this and changing the username password combination for a ticket that will be encrypted including a datetime stamp to expire the ticket. My questions.

- Would this be considered a best practice? If not, what better option do I have.
- Is using WSE3 “Microsoft Webservice Enhancement” necessary?
- Is WCF a better option if your kinda new to webservices?

The soap requests go over Https SSL and do not need further encryption on the client side. Thank you in advance.

Best regards,

Danny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer all these questions, but I can answer a few: IMO WCF is all you need as a tool set for this project, based on your description. WCF has a number of different flavors (http, TCP, etc.) and each has several different options for how you implement security.

WCF has options for user/pwd authentication, or you can construct a custom method, or you can construct a Login() function that takes a UserID and Password as parameters, returning a boolean. There are also options that allow you to authenticate BEFORE the main program receives the request. That's what the built-in UserID/Password authentication does.

If you implement SSL on the host, assuming you're using an http-centric binding, you won't need anything on the client side for encryption as the WCF software will take care of that, once you have both the Host and Client software configured properly. In effect, your WCF client app will behave like a browser, handing all the nasty cert stuff under the covers.

WCF also lets you a) run your web service as a stand-alone windows service (called "self hosted"), or b) allows you to configure your web service behind IIS, which has some advantages. WCF will also provide a WSDL for your clients if needed.

There are some other nice things about WCF; if 10,000 concurrent users hit your web service at 8 am on Monday, WCF automatically queues the requests it can't handle, processing them in order as it can. I've slammed our testing web service with numbers like that, and the program never broke down, processing >150 logins and file uploads / second. WCF is also works fine with Java, iOS and Android.